# Fourier integral/ Fourier transformation of an oscillatory function with FFT

Tags: fft, dft, numerical-integration

`f(x) = cos(x^2)` and `g(k) = pi^0.5 cos((pi*k)^2 - pi/4)` are a Fourier pair.

I want to reproduce `g(k)` by Fourier integrating `f(x)` using FFT, i.e.

approximating `Integrate[ f(x) * exp(2 pi * ikx), {x, -inf, inf} ]`

with `Sum[ fn * exp(2 pi * ik x_n), {n, 0, N-1} ] * Delta_x`

However the result agrees with `g(k)` only on very small `k` ranges if it agrees at all (the same code works well for smooth Fourier pairs e.g. the Gaussian functions). I guess the problem is choosing appropriate values for `N` and `Delta_x`.  Are there any established rules for how to choose them? Where can I find related topics in literature (I've read Numerical Recipe section 13.9 but it does not seem to solve my problem)?

Comment: Interesting, but you want one of the math-focused Stack Exchange sites. http://math.stackexchange.com/ (*for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields*) or mathoverflow.com (*research level math questions*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An FFT inherently windows f(x) with a rectangular window of length N.  This will produce different g(k) results for any k that is not exactly periodic within that window.  You can try picking Delta_X and N so that their result is an exact integer multiple of your desired k.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been very clear in my question. The other answer here [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143114/fourier-integral-fourier-transformation-of-an-oscillatory-function-with-fft) is more relevant to my problem. Thanks for the answer anyway!